# How can I Convert SQL Query to Odata Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, odata

Does someone know how I might convert the following SQL query to one which would run on Odata?

```
SELECT      FirstName, LastName, MobileNo, COUNT(1) as CNT
FROM        CUSTOMER
GROUP BY    FirstName, LastName, MobileNo;
```

Thanks!

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?

Comment: please update your question. Add SQL-Version, add Things you tried, add more Information. We are not here to make your work, we are here to help solving problems... Did you read any tutorial/howto?

Comment: Do you already have an OData Service? Or you are trying to building an OData service?

Answer (score 0):

Now the answer is to convert this query into Linq first then it works

```
var values = from i in CUSTOMER
                group i by new
                {
                    i.FirstName,
                    i.LastName,
                    i.MobileNo
                } into g
                select new
                {
                    g.Key.FirstName,
                    g.Key.LastName,
                    g.Key.MobileNo,
                    COUNT = g.Count()
                };
```